# Change authentication method for postgres superuser

Tags: postgresql, debian, psql

I am using psql to connect to a PostgreSQL database on Debian 10. I am trying to connect as the *postgres* user, to the default *postgres* database. By default, this is using the 'peer' authentication method, which does not require a password.

If I log in using the 'peer' authentication and set a password using the following command:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'myPassword';
```

The query executes successfully, however when I edit pg_hba.conf to change the authentication method from:

```
local    all            postgres                    peer
```

to:

```
local    all            postgres                    scram-sha-256
```

and restart the server, I get the following error:

```
~$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
~$
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the authentication method in PostgreSQL:

1. Open a terminal window
2. Change into the postgres bin directory

Example:  `cd /usr/local/pgsql/bin`

Note:  Depending on your install environment the path to the bin directory may vary.

3. Type `su – postgres` and press Enter.  This will change the logged in to the `postgres` user.
4. From the bin directory type `./psql`
5. Type:
    `ALTER USER your_username password 'new_password';` and press Enter.  `ALTER ROLE` should be displayed.
6. Type `\q` and press Enter
7. Open `/path_to_data_directory/pg_hba.conf`

Example:  `/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf`

8. Modify the line at the bottom of the config file to resemble one of these examples.

Note:  You will probably only have to change the word `trust` to `md5`.  The line or lines should already exist.

```
host     all        postgres                                   peer 
host     all        your_username      your.ip your.subnet     md5
```

9. Save the changes
10. Restart PostgreSQL service with `systemctl restart postgresql.service`

Answer (score 2):

Before you assign the password, you probably need to set the password_encryption to "scram-sha-256".  Otherwise, you stored the password in the md5 format, and such a password cannot be used to login when pg_hba.conf calls for "scram-sha-256".

The default setting of password_encryption is still md5.  It will change to be "scram-sha-256" in v14.

The error message sent to the unauthenticated user is intentionally vague.  The error message in the server log file will probably say `DETAIL:  User "postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM secret.`  (If it does not, then ignore this answer, and edit your question to tell us what it does say)

Comment: Thanks for adding this error message (`User "postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM secret`). This helped the search engines to guide me here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to 1st in the shell change to be the "postgres" user which you're not doing correctly above:

sudo su - postgres

Then you can do the following as peer auth:
psql -d postgres -U postgres

Also recommend you set a pw for postgres sql user:

\password postgres
& change the authentication method to "md5", not "peer".